# Adding integer values retrieved from EditText by saving the Bundle and passing it to other activity in Android

Tags: android

Could someone help me with below code. Two inputs are read from EditText in initial activity, saved in a Bundle and then passed to another activity to add them. First Activity:

---

```
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_input);
    firstNumber=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    secondNumber=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    addButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);
    addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick (View v){
            int val1=Integer.parseInt(firstNumber.getText().toString());
            int val2=Integer.parseInt(secondNumber.getText().toString());
            savedInstanceState.putInt("saved_message1",val1);
            savedInstanceState.putInt("saved_message2", val2);
            Intent addIntent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddActivity.class);
            addIntent.putExtra("passeddata", savedInstanceState);
            startActivity(addIntent);

        }
    });
```

---

### Then in Second activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);
    resultTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultField);
    int result;
    result=savedInstanceState.getInt("saved_message1")+savedInstanceState.getInt("saved_message2");
    resultTextView.setText(result);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Terrible code formatting. Please re-do it!

Comment: So what is the actual problem?

Comment: The code is executed, but when loaded in android phone, after clicking the add button in the first activity the application stops and doesn't go to second activity UI. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't and can't use that `savedInstanceState` bundle for passing information around to different activity.

Since `savedInstanceState` is not useable in your situation, I will skip more information about that and move to answering your question.

You basically have to put those values in the `Intent` data directly.

So, your `onClick` will look like this,

```
   public void onClick (View v){
        int val1=Integer.parseInt(firstNumber.getText().toString());
        int val2=Integer.parseInt(secondNumber.getText().toString());
        Intent addIntent=new Intent(YourActivity.this, AddActivity.class);
        addIntent.putExtra("saved_message1", val1);
        addIntent.putExtra("saved_message2", val2);
        startActivity(addIntent);
    }
});
```

Alternatively, you can create a `Bundle` then put data into that bundle and then pass that `Bundle` to intent as extra. It would be more work for exact same work under the hood.
It would look something like this,

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("saved_message1", val1);
bundle.putInt("saved_message2", val2);
addIntent.putExtras(bundle);
```

In your `AddActivity`, you would do this,

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
result=intent.getInt("saved_message1")+intent.getInt("saved_message2");
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! This way it works. But the question given in the book I read, asks explicitly the use of Bundle for this purpose.

Comment: @E.Roid That bundle is the `Bundle` class. Not the bundle you get for the saved state. Putting extras in the intent internally puts it in bundle only. So you're doing the same.

Comment: @E.Roid Please accept the answer if it solves your query. Thanks

Comment: @E.Roid I added code for your bundle based method, but it would be all same as I have mentioned above.

Comment: in AddActivity, getInt is not recognized. I did it this way: result=intentAdd.getIntExtra("saved_message1",0)+intentAdd.getIntExtra("saved_message2",0); but the application is still not working and stops when I click add in first activity.

Comment: @E.Roid The reason might be that you are using `getApplicationContext()` in your `Intent` creation. You must use your current activity context. So change it to `YourActivity.this`

Comment: at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:312)
 at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4417)
  at enayat.mc.de.exercise.AddActivity.onCreate(AddActivity.java:23)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.

Comment: With getApplicationContext() it should work! I think there should be other reason. Thank you for the feedbacks.